# Styling different parts of the same link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styling

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I want to style 1 part of a link differently, but for it still to act as a part of the link when it comes to hover, etc.

To explain,
I've got the following html:

```
<span class="link1">
<a href='http://www.google.com'>
Google
<span class="link2"> Link</span>
</a>
</span>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.link1 a {
color: #ff0000; 
}
.link2 a {
color: #00ff00;
}
```

This would hopefully make a link that had Google in red and Link in blue despite them being the same link.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That would be confusing and counter-intuitive. What's the point?

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but as mentioned by @CharlotteDan, in the second CSS class you are trying to target an anchor tag held within an element with the class `link2` which does not exist.

You could achieve what you are trying to do with the following:

**HTML**

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>
    Google
    <span>Link</span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    color: #ff0000;
}
a > span {
    color: #00ff00;
}
```

**JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/udfUS/**

Answer (score 0):

`.link2 a` does not work because there is no `a` in `.link2`. It would work if you made it

```
.link1 a .link2 {
    color: blue;
}
```